# Spring Boot Cloud Zuul - Reproducing Zuul Exception Forwarding Error

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

I want to reproduce `ZuulException: Forwarding error`. I tried to mistype `service-id`s of microservices and intentional `throw`s here and there but all of them resulted in `ClientException` - mostly `Load balancer does not have available server for client:`. So, how can I reproduce this exception?

Comment: write a filter that throws a `ZuulException`?

Comment: @spencergibb, I don't want to throw it, but cause it, let's say. I want to understand why it happens, because for example, when the `service-id` or URL is not resolvable, then it should be thrown (however, I am not 100% sure tho). I want `Forwarding error` to happen and want to see if `FallbackProvider` or `GlobalExceptionHandler` kick in, if that makes sense.